# BlueCloth error on windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bluecloth

Having a bit of a nightmare getting bluecloth to work on windows. I grabbed the gem from the site (since `gem install bluecloth` doesnt work). However, I can't seem to get the library to load

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'bluecloth'
LoadError: no such file to load -- bluecloth_ext
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5-x86-mingw32/lib/bluecloth.rb:156
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0>
```

any thoughts/suggestions? (besides don't use windows =P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using rubyinstaller.org instead of the one click installer, with the devkit plugin. This lets you build native extensions on windows without any headaches. I then got the .gem (not the mingw32 version) from the website, and did a gem install seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

From http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/59f3812381a195b5/adb40d04eabefe14?lnk=gst&q=bluecloth#adb40d04eabefe14:

```
C:\>gem install bluecloth --platform=ruby 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
Successfully installed bluecloth-2.0.5 
1 gem installed 
C:\>irb -rubygems 
irb(main):001:0> require 'bluecloth' 
=> true
```